# How to save to and from clipboard in lua (Windows)

Tags: windows, lua, clipboard

How do I save to and from (get clipboard data) clipboard in lua? (Windows)

Comment: There's no built-in way to do it in Lua, so all of the answers will most likely be "use library X".

Answer (score 2):

Simple! You can save and get information from the clipboard using the afxLua library:

```
 0 . go here - http://luaforge.net/projects/jaslatrix/
 1 . click on the "clipboard" link
 2 . click on "1.0.0"
 3 . select lua version accordingly. If unsure try "clipboard-1.0.0-Lua51.zip"
 4 . unzip the downloaded file
 5 . the documentation is inside of the clipboard.chm file.
 6 . place the clipboard.dll inside of your project folder (or in the same folder as the .lua)
 7 . add to the top of your code the following - require "clipboard"
 8 . to get clipboard data, assign a variable to clipboard.gettext()
 9 . to save data to the clipboard do this -  clipboard.setdata(yourVariableOrStringHere)
 [meta-numbers] 
 0 . Why did I make this?
    Because awhile ago, when I was a total newbie (lua is the first language I learned), I needed this for a project and was unable to figure out how, so the feature was never implemented despite it's importance. I was also a slightly scared of add-on libraries.
 1 . I am not jaslatrix nor am I advertising his library. However, when you search "clipboard API lua" on google, it is impossible to find anything except for c library tutorials, so I figured it'd be nice to share this.
```

Comment: Is there an update that works with current Lua (5.3)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_clipboard](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#get_clipboard) and [set_clipboard](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#set_clipboard) functions from [winapi](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html).